# Using Constants in Perl

Tags: perl, constants

I am trying to define constants in Perl using the `constant` pragma:

```
use constant {
    FOO => "bar",
    BAR => "foo"
};
```

I'm running into a bit of trouble, and hoping there's a standard way of handling it.

First of all...

I am defining a hook script for Subversion. To make things simple, I want to have a single file where the class (package) I'm using is in the same file as my actual script.

Most of this package will have constants involved in it:

```
 print "This is my program";

 package MyClass;

 use constant {
    FOO => "bar"
 };

 sub new { ... }
```

I would like my constant `FOO` to be accessible to my main program. I would like to do this without having to refer to it as `MyClass::FOO`. Normally, when the package is a separate file, I could do this in my main program:

```
use MyClass qw(FOO);
```

but, since my class and program are a single file, I can't do that. What would be the best way for my main program to be able to access my constants defined in my class?

The second issue...

I would like to use the constant values as hash keys:

```
$myHash{FOO} = "bar";
```

The problem is that `%myHash` has the literal string `FOO` as the key and not the value of the constant. This causes problems when I do things like this:

```
if (defined $myHash{FOO}) {
   print "Key " . FOO . " does exist!\n";
}
```

I could force the context:

```
if (defined $myHash{"" . FOO . ""}) {
```

I could add parentheses:

```
if (defined $myHash{FOO()}) {
```

Or, I could use a temporary variable:

```
my $foo = FOO;
if (defined $myHash{$foo}) {
```

None of these are really nice ways of handling this issue. So, what is the best way? Is there one way I'm missing?

By the way, I don't want to use `Readonly::Scalar` because it is 1). slow, and 2). not part of the standard Perl package. I want to define my hook not to require additional Perl packages and to be as simple as possible to work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to keep everything in the same file, you can define your constants package as follows:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

BEGIN {  # BEGIN means this will all happen at compile time
    package Constants;

    $INC{'Constants.pm'}++;     # tell `require` that the package is loaded
    use base 'Exporter';        # setup package to export
    our @EXPORT_OK = qw( PI );  # what to export

    use constant PI => 3.14159; # define your constant
}

package main;

use Constants qw( PI );  # use it like normal

print PI;
```

Then to fool the auto-quoting inside hash subscripts, you can write it like this:  `$hash{+PI}` or `$hash{(PI)}` or `$hash{PI()}` or `$hash{&PI}` or `$hash{::PI}` ... I could probably keep going, but I think you get the point.

The reason that `$INC{'Constants.pm'}++` is needed is because the `use Constants qw( PI );` line really means:

```
BEGIN {
    require 'Constants.pm';
    Constants->import( qw( PI ) );
}
```

And `require` will check `%INC` to see if the package has been loaded already.  So by giving it a true value (1 in this case), the `require 'Constants.pm';` portion of the `use` will become a no-op.

Comment: Didn't think about modifying the $INC array. That'll work. Thanks!

Comment: @David W. => Glad to help and welcome to SO.  Also, so you know `use constant PI => 3.14159` means the same thing as `sub PI {3.14159}` and I usually use the latter because its a little shorter and doesn't mislead one to think its something other than a sub.

Comment: Note that if you prefer not to mess with `%INC`, you can use `BEGIN { MyClass->import(qw(FOO)) }`
instead of `use MyClass qw(FOO);` (after setting MyClass up to use Exporter in the usual way).

Comment: Actually, it's the same as `sub PI () { 3.14159 }` (note the empty prototype).

Comment: I know this is really old, but does Constants.pm have to export anything for this to work?

Answer (score 4):

1. [Perl constants](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html) are not constants. They are compile-defined to be a particular kind of function that is inlined at compile-time.
2. I find that Perl 'constants' are more a pain to use than to not use. So, typically my approach is to use scalars with all uppercase. `my $PI = 3.14159;`.

Comment: You should make those scalars Readonly, or someday you'll be wondering why your circles are coming out square.

Comment: @Ether: A square is an digitized approximation of a circle - just doesn't have very high resolution. :)

Comment: If I had enough of a reputation, I'd vote this down. Good programming practices require the use of constants. If you don't like the "use constant" pragma, use the "Readonly" modules, or do it the old fashion typeglob way:  

*FOO = \"bar";  
our $FOO;  
print "Value of FOO is $FOO\n";   #Just like a scalar variable  
$FOO = "barfoo";     #Can't do this!  

Readonly isn't a standard module and can be slow. Typeglobbing is fast, but the syntax is weird.

Comment: @David: Yeah, constants in perl are sorta broken. So I do disciplined programming to deal with the problem.

Comment: @David: Good programming practice may require the use of constants, but it does not require their constant-ness to be enforced by the language. (Although it would definitely be nice if there were a clean, easy way of telling it to do so.)

Comment: @Dave: There is a way:

    use Readonly;
    Readonly::Scalar $PI = 4 * atan2 1, 1;

Comment: @dolmen Unfortunately, there's are two problems with Readonly

1. It's not part of the standard Perl package. Therefore, I have to depend upon the site to download and install which might not always be possible.

2. It's slow -- especially if you don't use the XL package with it.

Otherwise, I prefer the way Readonly works vs. the `use Constant`. In fact, for the longest time, I preferred typeglobbing:

    *PI = \3.1415926;
    our $PI;

This would allow me to treat constants as variables, but I still can't modify them.

Unfortunately, the Perl community went with `Use Constant`

Answer (score 4):

Barewords are automatically quoted when they appear in a hash lookup. You need to force the sub that implements the constant to be invoked instead:

```
$myHash{FOO}   = 'bar'; # doesn't work, bareword quoted
$myHash{+FOO}  = 'bar'; # okay
$myHash{&FOO}  = 'bar'; # okay
$myHash{FOO()} = 'bar'; # okay
```

Exporting functions and variables from one package to another is all symbol table manipulation. The `Exporter` module makes this easy for us, but it is not too hard to do it without a module.

```
package main;
sub stuff { return &FOO x 3 }
*FOO = *MyClass::FOO;
print stuff();               # "barbarbar"

package MyClass;
use constant FOO => "bar";
```

You could also have said

```
BEGIN { *main::FOO = *FOO }
```

under `package MyClass`.

Comment: Note: Wrapping the glob assignment in a `BEGIN` block is necessary to make `strict 'subs'` happy.

Comment: Thanks  for the answer. Yes, I figured out about the unitary operator (+) which looks the best.

I didn't think about symbol table modifications. That'll work.

If I had enough of a reputation, I'd vote this answer up.

Answer (score 0):

I second Eric Strom answer.

However, here is a an other way (but that exposes too much the Perl implementation):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Constants;
sub FOO() { 'bar' }
sub BAR() { 'foo' }
sub main::FOO() { FOO }
sub main::BAR() { BAR }

package main;

print FOO, BAR, "\n";
```